# % free ram of remote machines

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, remote-access

Reading on superuser/stackoverflow I couldn't come up with a script that acutally outputs the %-free ram (as seen in Windows task manager) of **several** remote machines (e.g. server1-server4). Here's what I have in terms of code, the platform should be windows, either CMD or powershell (or similar):

1) CMD, couldn't get the % of free ram (i.e. couldn't access the 'busy' ram to calculcate 'busy/total * 100'. [source](https://serverfault.com/questions/784513/how-to-use-wmic-to-connect-to-remote-machine-and-output-os-information-to-a-file#answers-header)): 
`wmic /NODE:"servername" /USER:"yourdomain\administrator" OS GET FreePhysicalMemory`

2) powershell ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470448/get-used-cpu-disk-memory-counters/36357846)), couldn't get the memory of remote machines (i.e. cannot get `Get-WmiObject` of the remote machine):

```
$system = Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem
$totalPhysicalMem = $system.TotalVisibleMemorySize
$freePhysicalMem = $system.FreePhysicalMemory
$usedPhysicalMem = $totalPhysicalMem - $freePhysicalMem
$usedPhysicalMemPct = [math]::Round(($usedPhysicalMem / $totalPhysicalMem) * 100,1)
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250783/how-to-get-free-physical-memory-of-remote-computer-using-powershell. Also, your example Powershell code is attempting to gather disk space information, which isn't included in your question. If this is also a requirement, you should mention it. It would be helpful if you added specifics of how the commands you're trying are failing rather than saying "couldn't get the memory".

Comment: I looked at that post, however as far as I have researched you cannot use `Get-Counter -Counter` for subsequent % calculation. I basically copy-pasted the code from the sources (I was hoping an expert could help me out quickly, reasoning that this would be a common question) - but I will further comment the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this fairly generalizable script, which gives a percentage of free ram. For percentage of used ram simply add `$a=$b-$a`.

```
$a=0
$b=0
$strComputer = "localhost"
$a=Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $strComputer | fl *freePhysical* | Out-String
$b=Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $strComputer | fl *totalvisiblememory* | Out-String
$a = $a -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'
$b = $b  -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'
[math]::Round($a/$b*10000)/100
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the method of Connecting to WMI Remotely with PowerShell from
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309377(v=vs.85).aspx

I have used .NET to Format Numbers 
example from here. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx

```
$Servers = @("localhost")

foreach ($Server in $Servers){

$OS = get-wmiobject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Impersonation 3 -computername $Server

foreach ($Item in $OS){
        $RAM = "{0:N6}" -f ($Item.TotalVisibleMemorySize)/1kB
        $FREE = "{0:N6}" -f ($Item.FreePhysicalMemory)/1kB
        $Server + "`t" + "{0:P0}" -f ($FREE/$RAM)
        }
}
```

**EDIT**

To resolve issues with number formats across PS and .net versions you can use either the Decimal or Fixed point format rather than number to correct. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-decimal-d-format-specifier

```
$Servers = @("localhost")

foreach ($Server in $Servers){

$OS = get-wmiobject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Impersonation 3 -computername $Server

foreach ($Item in $OS){
        $RAM = "{0:D6}" -f ($Item.TotalVisibleMemorySize)/1kB
        $FREE = "{0:D6}" -f ($Item.FreePhysicalMemory)/1kB
        $Server + "`t" + "{0:P0}" -f ($FREE/$RAM)
        }
}
```

**OR**

```
$Servers = @("localhost")

foreach ($Server in $Servers){

$OS = get-wmiobject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Impersonation 3 -computername $Server

foreach ($Item in $OS){
        $RAM = "{0:F6}" -f ($Item.TotalVisibleMemorySize)/1kB
        $FREE = "{0:F6}" -f ($Item.FreePhysicalMemory)/1kB
        $Server + "`t" + "{0:P0}" -f ($FREE/$RAM)
        }
}
```

Comment: did not work out of the box for me:
`Cannot convert value "20'823'476.000000" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:8 char:9
+         $RAM = "{0:N6}" -f ($Item.TotalVisibleMemorySize)/1kB
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger`

Comment: @user2305193 I have updated answer to hopefully overcome your issue.